# How to use UDDI's asynchronous subscription service from a client?

Tags: java, asynchronous, uddi

How might one go about implementing the client side for jUDDI v3 asynchronous subscription to listen for business entities to be added or deleted? My understanding is that a subscription is created and then jUDDI somehow calls a webservice. How do I create a subscription that points back to my webservice?  I've looked through the tutorials and examples, but those seem to focus on synchronous subscriptions. Here is what I've read so far:

[V3 API Docs](http://ws.apache.org/juddi/apidocs3/index.html)

[Apache jUDDI User Help](http://ws.apache.org/juddi/docs/3.0/userguide/html/chap-Subscription.html)

[Another Tutorial from developer.com](http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3088901/UDDI-V3-Subscriptions-Part-I.htm)

I'm guessing this is fairly obvious and I'm missing something, so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jUDDI is alive and well.

We have a recent example of doing exactly what you asked for.

Java: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/more-uddi-samples/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/samples/SubscriptionCallbackExample.java

.NET: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/juddi-client.net-sample/org.apache.juddi.client.samples/SubscriptionCallbackExample.cs

The jUDDI mailing lists is a good resource. There's also someone usually on freenode #juddi IRC.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I think jUDDI is a great concept and it's good to hear it is back under development. I'll remember it for future projects.

Answer (score -1):

Adding more examples and documentation is in the [jUDDI issue tracking](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JUDDI-342). Vote for it or donate to draw more attention to asynchronous subscription.

**Update**

The examples were updated in 3.1.0 and as spy said jUDDI is under development.

Comment: Yeah... jUDDI seems to be dying the slow death, so if you want UDDI asynchronous subscription you will likely need to fix it up yourself. If I remember right there were some bugs that needed to be fixed to make it come together end to end.